# Using the QuickSort/SortVals VB Script on a selection, not just the active cell

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Is there an easy way to get this code to execute for a selection, not simply the active cell? My brain is fried and I can't make this work...I need to be able to do this for about 10,000 rows.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortVals()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(ActiveCell.Text, ",")

    ' trim values so sort will work properly
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Trim(arr(i))
    Next i

    ' sort
    QuickSort arr, LBound(arr), UBound(arr)

    ' load sorted values back to cell
    Dim comma As String
    comma = ""
    ActiveCell = ""
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        ActiveCell = ActiveCell & comma & CStr(arr(i))
        comma = ","
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)

  Dim pivot   As Variant
  Dim tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

     While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If

  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

End Sub
```

Comment: You already have what is needed for one cell. Could you not loop through all cells from the `Selection` range in Excel. I shall make an answer in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I update the macro to have a loop.

Using the following sample

```
Before
threat,concert,pin
saw,bench,danger,tongue,straw
republic,stars,pie,sermon,tongue,prize,puppet
prison,lollipop
crown,bench,clown,price,apple pie,ankle,laser
```

I run the following.Note i am ommiting the QuickSort since that was not edited.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortValsSelection()
    Dim rngSelection As Range
    Dim rngSingleCell As Range
    Set rngSelection = Selection

    For Each rngSingleCell In rngSelection.Cells
        Call SortVals(rngSingleCell)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub SortVals(rngRange As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim strSorted As String
    arr = Split(rngRange.Text, ",")

    ' trim values so sort will work properly
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Trim(arr(i))
    Next i

    ' sort
    QuickSort arr, LBound(arr), UBound(arr)

    ' load sorted values back to cell
    Dim comma As String
    comma = ""
    strSorted = ""
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        strSorted = strSorted & comma & CStr(arr(i))
        comma = ","
    Next i

    rngRange.Value = strSorted
End Sub
```

I removed references to the active cell and replaced it wiht the parameter rngRange which is a single cell that is part of your selection. The following was outputted after i selected all the cells

```
concert,pin,threat
bench,danger,saw,straw,tongue
pie,prize,puppet,republic,sermon,stars,tongue
lollipop,prison
ankle,apple pie,bench,clown,crown,laser,price
```

Comment: A sample row of data would be:                                     MOUNT PLEASANT RD,CHARLES ST E,JARVIS ST
YONGE ST,CARLTON ST,COLLEGE ST
YONGE ST,CHURCH ST,DAVENPORT RD...I want to be able to take these values and arrange them by row in alphabetical order, but right now its just giving the same result over and over.

Comment: Where would the first chunk of code you provided be placed?

Comment: Apologize i missed making a change on where you are putting the data back into the cell after arranging it. Making an end to end update to my answer now.